# selector to match elements not nested within another selector?

Tags: css

I have a bunch of divs which I nest arbitrarily:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>Apple</div>
    <div>
      <div>Banana</div>
      <div>Grape</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>Craisin</div>
</div>
```

I make their contents pink with a rule like this:

```
div { color: pink; }
```

I want to be able to add the `special` class to any of those `div`s to cancel out the pink rule for it *and all of its children*. For example, if I add the `special` class to *this* div,

```
<div>
  <div class="special">
    <div>Apple</div>
    <div>
      <div>Banana</div>
      <div>Grape</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>Craisin</div>
</div>
```

then "Apple," "Banana," and "Grape" should no longer be pink.

**Can I tweak my rule to only match divs that aren't nested inside a `.special`?**

I'm not looking for a solution involves writing a rule for `.special` that cancels out every style defined on `div`. For example, this is not a good solution even though it works:

```
.special, .special div { color: black !important; }
```

My actual styles are more complicated than just changing the color, and there are other rules with selectors like `div span` which I would also like to disable with the `special` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent children/descendants from inheriting inheritable style properties using CSS.

The style properties for the descendants have to explictly be reset.

Comment: So there's no way to write something like `.div:noparents(.special)`?

Comment: @alltom You cannot select a children, then the parents. "Parent selectors" do not exist in CSS. The only way to achieve such is: `div{color:red;}div.special, .special div {color:black;}` (assuming that black is the default color).